# Optimize the performance of an API that returns 200K rows as Json

Tags: c#, android, sql, asp.net, webapi

Using asp.net Web API c# I'm developing an API that returns
between 100,000 - 200,000 rows/records from a table using SQL Server 2017 to the client (Android application).

Client will need to fetch this data once or maximum twice a day based on some condition and store it on the local db SQLite.

The API returns the data in Json format as below

```
{

   "MyData": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "BillRefNo": 10001995,
            "Barcode": 1000189500001,
            "BillRefCID": 915,
            "IsDuplicate": 0,
            "IsDeclined": 0,
            "IsAuditRequest": 0,
            "IsRevRequest": 0,
            "NoOfProducts": 0,
            "IsCompleted": 0
        }

}
```

Now when I hit the API using postman, It takes sometimes from 4-7 minutes to retrieve the result. I think it's important to mention that when I debug the API it returns the result for example in 3 minutes and in postman itself it takes 1-2 minutes to display this huge data.

The size of the response is 28.4MB.

Now I want to optimize this , especially the response time more than the storage. Although it's important too.

My biggest concern is when different/multiple clients will hit this API. I believe the time will increase (I'm not sure). And I don't know if the server where the API is deployed will be affected or not.

Now I did some research on how to optimize this. But I need an expert opinion on which one is the most suitable and most efficient and will likely improve it.

1. Compressing the data in API before returning it to client. But I'm
   not sure     how long it will take for the client to decompress the
   data (Extra step) and     then store this decompressed data in local
   db.
2. Convert JSON to CSV in API before returning it to client. (I'm not
   sure if     this is doable or not).
3. From SQL Server, Export the table as CSV file(Not     sure if this
   is doable ) and     then read this file from the client side.I'm not
   sure    how fast the reading process from client side will
   be.
4. Changing the JSON key names. For example from     `BillRefNo` change
   it to `1`. By this I will reduce
   the number of text returned and it might improve the
   performance (Not sure)

I have been thinking about this for weeks. Any idea , suggestion , thoughts would be highly appriciated!

Comment: Consider adding paging to your API. Have the client applications fetch the data sequentially as pages over multiple requests. This would also increase reliability as if the request fails, the client can pick up where the last got to, rather than having to request everything again.

Comment: @MartinCostello let's say I divided the result into 3. So client will call API 3 times first time still the data is relatively huge so it might take 1 min , then second call 1 min & third call 3 minutes so the sum will be 3 again. Does it logical how I'm thinking? or is it not like that.

Comment: Well the problem is that your individual requests shouldn't be huge, that's the limiting factor you have here. You need to be breaking your payloads down into more manageable chunks, say a few/tens of kilobytes at most.

Comment: @MartinCostello So by paging , what I will improve?

Comment: You will reduce the payload sizes, which will improve the overall performance by reducing the memory footprint, time to process requests, and also improve reliability because it is easier to handle transient network errors with smaller payloads.

Comment: @MartinCostello Great , I will give this a try. Thank you Martin

Comment: you can compress it, but you can also after the first time, later send only the update record and merger them. Keep on an other table the update point

Comment: You mentioned that you thinking about converting the JSON to CSV before returning it. So, using another format is on the table, right? Hence, I suggest you also take a look at gRPC. It transfers data in binary format and seems to be perfect for you needs. Concerning the compression: Compression can be done by the HTTP layer transparently for the client. I think it doesn't make much sense to do it manually.

Comment: @Xaver I haven’t heard of gRPC I will look into it.Regarding compression , if it done through http layer how the client can decompress the data? Manually?

Comment: @Aristos I didn’t get what you mean

Comment: @MartinCostello As I know paging is used when we have pages or scrolling page with many segments of data. For me I still want to get full result 200K at a time but with paging. Will it still helps? Means the Client will keep waiting until the paging is done

Comment: @Nates: On your client application, you retrieve your JSON file by using a HTTP client, right? Typically, you can configure this client to support compression. If the server also supports compression, the server will compress the data and the clients HTTP library will decompress it. You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: @Nates: Regarding gRPC, there was a nice talk about it at .NET Conf 2020. You can find the video here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2020/High-performance-Services-with-gRPC-Whats-new-in-NET-5

Comment: @Xaver I got it , I will try this as well! Thank you so much